# Saving images in AWS from backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, image-uploading

We need to save product's images in AWS. There are 2 ways, it can be uploaded from frontend(website or mobile application) or from backend.

On frontend side we need to store AWS credentials, which can be an issue. So, we want to go with upload on AWS from backend. The flow will be: user select an image, and upload it to backend, and backend upload it to AWS.

Is this ok? What issues can appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with uploading it to your backend, presumably an ec2 instance, and then having the ec2 instance upload the file to s3 - thats a secure way of doing it and a method I often use.

However, you do not need to expose your aws credentials to the browser if you would prefer to do the upload directly from your browser to s3 - you would just need to add AWS Cognito to the equation.

Using cognito you can get temporary credentials that will allow you to do the upload without compromising security.

https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/

Answer (score 1):

You can also used a pre-signed S3 URL (see: [Uploading Objects Using Pre-Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)) which you generate in the backend and pass to the frontend app. Then the flow would be something like this:

1. Request a pre-signed URL from your backend service
2. The frontend app PUTs the file to the signed URL

Signing the URL on the backend would look something like this (Ruby):

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-east-1')
url = s3.bucket('my-bucket').object('name-of-file').presigned_url(:put)
```

And on the frontend you could simply do something like this using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
fetch(signedUrl, { method: 'PUT', body: file })
```